# perl + one line change string only if match two words in line

Tags: perl

I have the following line in file

```
    <getTheIP ConnectType='INFO' Host='machine_num_1' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>
```

I need to change the IP 12.34.3.9 to other IP for example 3.4.5.6 
but only if I have in line the first word match **ConnectType** and the second word match **machine_num_1**

Please advice how I can do that with perl one line commnand ( I need to run this perl line command from bash script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>cat test.txt
 <getTheIP ConnectType='INFO' Host='machine_num_1' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>
 <getTheIP ConnectFour='INFO' Host='machine_num_41' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>
 <getTheIP ConnectThree='INFO' Host='machine_num_31' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>
 <getTheIP ConnectType='INFO' Host='machine_num_21' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>

>perl -lpe "if (/ConnectType/ && /'machine_num_1'/) {s/(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/3.4.5.6/};" test.txt
 <getTheIP ConnectType='INFO' Host='machine_num_1' VirtualIp='3.4.5.6'/>
 <getTheIP ConnectFour='INFO' Host='machine_num_41' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>
 <getTheIP ConnectThree='INFO' Host='machine_num_31' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>
 <getTheIP ConnectType='INFO' Host='machine_num_21' VirtualIp='12.34.3.9'/>
```

Comment: can I add the "-i" flag to write to file?

Comment: you can pipe the output to a file with perl [...] > myfile